# Diagonalizing matrix question for a ${M_{4x4}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
          3 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

Determine if this 4x4 matrix is diagonalizable.  How would you guys find the characteristic polynomial of this?

Comment: Are you stuck somewhere?  Or do you just want this definition? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial

Comment: I just want to know what is the easiest way to find the characteristic polynomial for this equation.  I am stuck somewhere

Comment: I would find it by definition, it is quite simple $4\times 4$ determinant with many zeros.

Comment: By expanding $A-\lambda I_4$ with respect to the first column. Btw: Don't await us to do it for you.

Comment: Wait I found it $(x-2)^2  (x+2)^2$

Comment: @NTT Yeah, looks good.

Comment: Of course, knowing the characteristic polynomial doesn’t tell you whether or not the matrix is diagonalizable, but it’s a good first step.

Comment: It is a pleasure to see that you have worked towards the solution. It remains a last step, as @amd just said you: prove that the dimension of the eigenspaces are equal to the order of multiplicity of the roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: You should find that $dim(E_{-2})=2$ but unfortunately $dim(E_{2})=1<2$, thus your matrix is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly painless to use the definition.

$$
 p(\lambda) = \det \left( \mathbf{A} -\lambda \mathbf{I} \right)
$$

You will end up at 
$$
 p(\lambda) = \left( \lambda^{2} - 4 \right)^{2}
$$

The solution is rather long - do you need that?